# Data Binding for Flyout page "'No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Command", or mismatching type between value and property."

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui

I'm developing a mobile app using .Net MAUI and having trouble with data binding in XAML. I have `MainPage.xaml` that receives data from `MainPageViewModel.cs` which inherits from `ObservableObject`.

In `Flyout.cs`, I have `Title`, `IconSource`, and `Command` and get them in `<DataTemplate>` in `Mainpage.xaml`. I pass values to each of the property in `<CollectionView.ItemSource>` and only to `Command`, I am passing a string of method that is defined in `MainPageViewModel.xaml.cs`.

I am confused about how to perform data binding here.
Values for `Title` and `IconSource` are bound correctly and visible, but only `Command` is not working.

How can I get this to work?

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Realizer.ViewModels"
            xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Realizer.Models"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Realizer.Pages"
            x:Class="Realizer.Pages.MainPage"
            x:DataType="vm:MainPageViewModel"
            Title="Home">

    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <ContentPage Title="Home page" BackgroundColor="LightGrey">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <CollectionView>
                    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type models:Flyout}">
                            <models:Flyout Title="Home"
                                       IconSource="home.png"
                                       Command="{Binding GoHomeCommand}"/>
                            <models:Flyout Title="Clients"
                                        IconSource="person.png"
                                        Command="{Binding GoToClientsPageCommand}"/>
                            <models:Flyout Title="Products"
                                        IconSource="medicine_bag.png"
                                       Command="{Binding GotoProductsPageCommand}"/>
                        </x:Array>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="20, 5">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
                                   Scale="1.5"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Text="{Binding Title, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
                                    Command="{Binding Command,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    HeightRequest="60"
                                    Padding="0,0,110,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <Label Text="this is it"
                       Margin="20"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>

    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="Navy"
                        BarTextColor="Black"
                        Title="Home">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Home" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="this is detail"
                               Margin="20"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </ContentPage>

            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>

</FlyoutPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Realizer.ViewModels;

namespace Realizer.Pages;

public partial class MainPage : FlyoutPage
{
    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel) {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace Realizer.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        { 
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void GoToClientsPage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void GoHome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi home");
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void GoToProductsPage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi pro");
        }
    }
}
```

Flyout.cs

```
namespace Realizer.Models
{
    internal class Flyout
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string IconSource { get; set; }
        public string Command { get; set; }     
        }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>();
```

I referred to this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/5Qga2pniN78?si=hJMy0cDihwAczw3w) when writing the code.

I tried `Command="{Binding GoHomeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainPageViewModel}}}}"/>`, but I am not even sure what I'm doing here.

Comment: add a [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0) property to your `DataTemplate`

Comment: @Jason, and what do I assign to that property?

Comment: Please read the docs I linked to.  It should be the type of the object that you are binding to

Comment: @Jason It's complaining about the Command in <CollectionView.ItemsSource>. Adding DataType property didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of figuring out the data type, I made a "OnClick" method in "MainPageViewModel.cs", called it in `<Button>` in `<DataTemplate>` in "MainPage.xaml", and deleted each "Command" property in `<model:flyout>`.

`MainPageViewModel.cs`:

```
  [RelayCommand]
  private async void OnClick(string page){
    if(page == "Home") ...//page navigation here
    else if (page == "Clients")...

  }
```

`MainPage.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate>
          ...
       <Button Grid.Column="1"
               Margin="5"
               Text="{Binding Title, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"
               Command="{Binding ClickCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainPageViewModel}}}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding Title, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Flyout}}}"/>
         ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code to achieve it:

Flyout2.cs:

```cs
public class Flyout2
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string IconSource { get; set; }
    public ICommand Commandd { get; set; }
}
```

MainPageViewModel2.cs:

```cs
public partial class MainPageViewModel2
{
    public ObservableCollection<Flyout2> Flyouts { get; set; }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void GoToClientsPage ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("hi");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void GoHome ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("hi home");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void GoToProductsPage ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("hi pro");
    }
    public MainPageViewModel2 () 
    { 
        CreateFlyouts (); 
        
    }
    
    void CreateFlyouts ()
    {
        Flyouts = new ObservableCollection<Flyout2> {
            new Flyout2 { Title = "Home", IconSource = "home.png",
                          Commandd = GoHomeCommand },
            new Flyout2 { Title = "Clients", IconSource = "person.png",
                          Commandd = GoToClientsPageCommand },
            new Flyout2 { Title = "Products", IconSource = "medicine_bag.png",
                          Commandd = GoToProductsPageCommand }
        };
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Flyouts}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid Padding="20, 5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"
                                   Scale="1.5"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                    Command="{Binding Commandd}"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    HeightRequest="60"
                                    Padding="0,0,110,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```